# After migration from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 Command UI Handler Command Action is not working for the Custom button

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-form, custom-actions

We have custom buttons in the ribbon. Button will be enabled based on the status.

CommandUIHandleris are working well for All button except for Submit and Resubmit buttons after migrating from SharePoint 2010 to 2013.
[image]

We didn't find any solution related to this issue,Please let me know the solution to the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the relevant JavaScript function "SubmitOrCancelProject". Probably input parameter values *(ex:{SelectedItemId})* are different and breaking the functionality.

Take a look on [CommandUIHandler element](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/commanduihandler-element) to get more details on custom actions.